# xgoogle google search return top url

Tags: python, search, web-scraping, xgoogle

I am using xgoogle to return top 10 url for a given keyword. The code is:

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch
gs = GoogleSearch("google scraper")
gs.results_per_page = 10
results = gs.get_results()
for res in results:
 print res.url.encode('utf8')
```

The problem is it only prints few url in random order. Any help would be appreciated, thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the urls from google.

```
from google import search
for url in search('put your search query here', stop=15):
    print(url)
```

you can limit the no. of urls by using stop=any no. you want.

do reply if it worked for you.

Regards
Sourabh

Comment: It returned me relevant results but all of the results it showed were not similar with that of the search results.

Comment: Its giving you the best related query result. you should refine your keyword relevancy in this case like search for (any player your favorite with his team name)